# I need the selected combobox to display automatically its value in the textfield i don't know whats wrong

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, combobox

I need the selected combobox to display automatically its value in the textfield i don't know whats wrong it doesn't have any error but it doesn't display its value here's my code

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        if ((String.valueOf(cb.getSelectedItem()).equals("Single"))) {
            rate.setText(String.valueOf(400));
        }
        else if ((String.valueOf(cb.getSelectedItem()).equals("Twin Bedded"))) {
            rate.setText(String.valueOf(600));
        }
        else if ((String.valueOf(cb.getSelectedItem()).equals("Suite"))) {
            rate.setText(String.valueOf(1000));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add some logging to find out what's going on. I'd suggest to log `cb.getSelectedItem()` after your `if` statement. Which data do you put into the `JComboBox`?

Comment: I can not duplicate the problem. This code works for me.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. WE are not interested in your entire application. Your MRE would be a JFrame with a JComboBox and JTextField. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code you post.